# Routing rules for MVC 2 in ASP.Net (c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

How can I add a routing rule that takes this URL

http://localhost:57334/Blog/index.aspx?Id=23

and converts to this:

http://localhost:57334/Blog/Id/23/blog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Routing rules typically interprets the urls you give and maps them to resources meant to handle those requests. Your url suggests you are using webforms and not asp.net mvc.

What i think you need is URL rewriting... you could check out

[this link](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/)

Hope this helps

Comment: The problem is that we are changing from Webforms to MVC. So I need to support the old URL.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you are using IIS 6 or 7

If you are using IIS6 you will need to install an add-in and you will need to install something like:

www.isapirewrite.com or www.urlrewriter.net

If you are using IIS7 take a look at http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/